# removing trailing slashes from django multi language url pattern (i18n_patterns)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, trailing-slash

I'm trying to get rid of trailing slash from urls. Currently the web-server successfully removes slashes and APPEND_SLASH = false Everything works fine but I have a problem with the localized homepage:

http://example.com/en/ - ok
http://example.com/en - Page not found (404)

I add this class to Middleware:

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import translation

class RemoveTrailingSlashFromMultilingualURLsMiddleware:
def **init**(self, get_response):
self.get_response = get_response

```
def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Check if the URL ends with a language code and a slash
    language_code = translation.get_language()
    if request.path.endswith(f'/{language_code}/') and request.path != f'/{language_code}/':
        new_path = request.path.rstrip('/')
        return redirect(new_path)
```

and add MIDDLEWARE to setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
# ... other middleware
'blog.middleware.RemoveTrailingSlashFromMultilingualURLsMiddleware',
# ... other middleware
```

]

But it doesn't work and keeps giving 404 not found error if possible help me to solve my problem

thanks a lot